# Identify the ng-grid on which the sort event was fired

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I have two ng-grids in the same view/partial and need to identify on which ng-grid was the sort event fired. How do I do that? I am using the `ngGridEventSorted` event.

Comment: I was about to answer your exactly needed, why you deleted question? please undelete and I'll push the answer there perfect what you were after and give me the link after undeleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the scope on which the event was fired with `event.targetScope`

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventSorted', function(event, args) {
   var targetScope = event.targetScope;
   // inspect targetScope's properties to differentiate between the two grids
});
```

Another way would be to create two wrapping div's around the grids, each with their own controller that handles the event.

```
<div ng-controller="controllerOne">
   <ng-grid ...>
</div>

<div ng-controller="controllerTwo">
   <ng-grid ...>
</div>
```

Comment: i  did it according to the column number

Answer (score 1):

That what you need:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventSorted', function(event,data) {
            if ($scope.gridOptions1.gridId==event.targetScope.gridId){
                ...
            }
            if ($scope.gridOptions2.gridId==event.targetScope.gridId){
                ...
            }
        });
```

And no need to define gridId.